# Number of values in a discrete random walk exceeding some level

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have some discrete random walk defined $X_0 = 0$ and $X_i = X_{i-1} + Y_i$, where the $Y_i$ are iid random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Using the central limit theorem, one can approximate $\mathbb{P}[X_i > f(i)]$ for some function $f$. Using linearity of expectations, one can then find the expected number of times that $X_i > f(i)$ in some interval.

My question is whether there is a way to prove anything about the distribution of the number of times that $X_i > f(i)$ holds. I would also be interested if there was a way to do this assuming something about $Y_i$, for example if $Y_i$ is $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Is the model $X_i=X_{i-1}+Y_i$ with $(Y_i)$ i.i.d.?

Comment: @Did Yes, that is right.

Comment: At present, the question is too general to have a satisfying answer. Which functions $f$ do you have in mind?

Comment: I am particularly interested in $C\sqrt{\log \log n}$.

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in the ladder variables for a random walk (create a new random walk $Z_i := Y_i - f(i)$ -- I don't think you suffer any loss of generality by doing so) http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/RW.pdf. I'm not sure which textbooks or links to point you to because there are a lot of resources discussing them. http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/statistik/alsmeyer/MRWLadder.pdf

Comment: Also, discussion of the specific case of $C \sqrt{\log \log n}$ should come up in many expositions on the Law of the Iterated Logarithm.